# Chrome app semitransparent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating an app for google chrome.
I'm trying to create a floating window like Hangouts app, checkout this image:

[image]

Here is the code on my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test app",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions" : [
      "alwaysOnTopWindows"
  ],
  "icons": { "16": "calculator-16.png", "128": "calculator-128.png" }
}
```

and this is the js file until now:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    var options = {
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 32,
            'height': 64
        },
        resizable: false,
        frame: 'none',
        alwaysOnTop: true
    };

    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', options);
});
```

It creates the window without border which is correct, but it still have a white background, I want to add a small play icon (like hangouts app), but it seems that must be a square window only.

Any help?

Comment: Is the screenshot from a mac?

Comment: Image is not showing so I cannot post this as answer. But from the description, it looks like you need to create `window` of type [`panel` or `detached_panel`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#type-CreateType). But as these types are only supported when flag is set so this wouldn't be appropriate for production use.
Hangout app is whitelisted in Chrome's source code so it doesn't need the flags to be set.